# Can someone explain the following snippet of linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I am getting confused with the last three lines of the code in the while loop. We basically have to return the sum of the linked list.

```
ListNode* addTwoNumbers(ListNode* l1, ListNode* l2) {
        int sum=0;
        ListNode *l3 = NULL;
        ListNode **node = &l3;
        
        while(l1 != NULL || l2 != NULL || sum>0)
        {
            if(l1!=NULL)
            {
                sum+=l1->val;
                l1=l1->next;
            }
            if(l2!=NULL)
            {
                sum +=l2->val;
                l2=l2->next;
            }
            (*node) = new ListNode(sum%10);
            sum /= 10;
            node = &((*node) -> next); 
        }
        return l3;
    }
```

Comment: Tip: In C++ use `nullptr` instead of C `NULL`.

Comment: It's not clear why you're using a double pointer here. This seems like a convoluted way of just changing the `->next` pointer.

Comment: The code is building a new linked list.  The double-pointer trick is useful for dealing with the `head` of the list without having to use a separate `if` branch to assign it.

Comment: @tadman "*Since l3 is never assigned, ..*"` - yes, it is, by the `*node =` statement. On the 1st loop iteration, `node` points at `l3`, so `l3` is assigned to. On the 2nd loop iteration, `node` points at `l3->next`, so that pointer is assigned to, and so on for the next node, and the next node, etc...

Comment: @RemyLebeau Oh, this is just *strange* code. There's absolutely no reason for that.

Comment: @tadman Yes, there is.  In fact, this is fairly standard practice when building a new linked list. Otherwise, you would have do something like `if (!l3) { l3 = new ListNode(...); ...  previous = l3; } else { previous->next = new ListNode(...); ... previous = previous->next; }` instead. The double-pointer trick avoids that.

Comment: `l1`, `l2` and `l3` aren't particularly good names. When you're writing your own code learn form how bad names made the function harder to read and use descriptive names that provide information about what the variables represent. People reading and trying to understand your code in the future will say nicer things about you at your retirement party.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is creating a new linked list containing values calculated from 2 other linked lists.  The head of the new list is pointed at by the `l3` variable.  Before the loop is entered, the `node` variable is set to point at the memory address of the `l3` variable.

On the 1st loop iteration, the statement `(*node) = new ListNode(sum%10);` creates a new `ListNode` object and assigns it to the `ListNode*` variable that `node` is pointing at, which is `l3`.  Then the statement `node = &((*node) -> next);` sets `node` to point at the memory address of the `next` member of that newly created `ListNode` object.

On the 2nd loop iteration, the statement `(*node) = new ListNode(sum%10);` creates a new `ListNode` object and assigns it to the `ListNode*` variable that `node` is pointing at, which is the `next` member of the previously created `ListNode` object.  Then the statement `node = &((*node) -> next);` sets `node` to point at the memory address of the `next` member of that newly created `ListNode` object.

And so on, until the loop ends when there are no more `ListNode` objects to create.  Then the function returns the new list being pointed at by `l3`.

Answer (score 2):

This function creates a new linked list that will contain the sum of digits (numbers) from two other lists that are passed in to the function as arguments.

So, for example, if the passed two lists contain the following data:

```
2 -> 4 -> 6 -> null
3 -> 5 -> 7 -> 9 -> null
```

(that is the first list contains the representation of the number `642` and the second list contains the representation of the number `9753`; each node contains a digit of the given number) then the resulting list will be equal to:

```
5 -> 9 -> 3 -> 0 -> 1 -> null
```

That is the resulting list will contain the number `10395` that is equal to the sum of numbers `642` and `9753`.

The function returns a pointer to the head node of the new list. That is, relative to the example shown above, the function returns a pointer to the node that contains `5`.

The function should be declared like:

```cpp
ListNode* addTwoNumbers( const ListNode* l1, const ListNode* l2);
```

because the passed in lists are not changed within the function.

Answer (score 0):

The snippet above is to find the sum of numbers.
Lets say you want to add 4385 and 8394.

The steps you'd follow to add them are:

> 5+4=9 *which is rightmost digit* 
> 8+9=17, *so 7 is the next left digit and 1 carried over*
> 3+3+1=7 *which is next left digit*
> 4+8=12 *which is leftmost pair of digit*

and the answer is 12779

Your Code is just replicating the same procedure, choosing the digit to write at a place is done by **sum%10** while what to carry over is done by **sum/=10**. Lastly the whole answer is woven up by the last line where l3 is created.